# How to make a search through H2 tags only

Tags: javascript, ajax, search

I have a single page with lots of H2 and paragraphs.
How to make a javascript/ajax (or other) search bar to search only through the H2 tags with dropdown suggestion and with no database?

Comment: I think you should first split your problem into smaller problems, and then ask for more concrete things. There are multiple approaches to achieve what you need and they depend on factors that you don't mention (do you want to parse generated HTML? do you have that HTML stored in a file? can you use PHP? do you have/want an API?).

Comment: does it have to be html file? can't you use XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to search for occurrences with `:contains()`. The script also looks for the anchors (id) of the `<h2>` to link them.

```js
// Make :contains() case insensitive
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
  return function(elem) {
    return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  };
});

// Search on type
var result;
$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
  result = '';
  // Search h2 caontaining search term
  $('h2:contains("' + $('#search').val() + '")').each(function(index) {
    result += '<li><a href="#' + $(this).attr('id') + '">' + $(this).text() + '</a></li>';
  });
  // Show results
  $('#searchResults').html('<ul>' + result + '</ul>');
});
```

```css
#searchResults {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Search titles:
<input id="search" />
<div id="searchResults"></div>

<h2 id="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
<p>consectetur adipiscing elit.<br/>Ut venenatis, diam nec laoreet rutrum, est dolor vehicula leo, eu euismod ex risus id felis.<br/>Nam non odio eget libero commodo iaculis ac sed leo.<br/>Sed velit ex, elementum et lobortis id, porta nec nunc.<br/>Curabitur gravida risus in blandit cursus.<br/>onec fermentum nulla sem, et interdum lectus tincidunt id.<br/>Sed pharetra odio arcu.<br/> Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.<br/>Vestibulum semper lorem leo, sed congue massa posuere et.<br/>Proin porta lorem eu metus ultricies dictum.<br/>Cras sit amet molestie nisi.<br/>Phasellus eu congue ipsum, id tristique urna.<br/>Quisque in leo vel nisi rutrum auctor ut ac mauris.<br/>Maecenas consectetur ipsum ultricies orci egestas fringilla.<br/>Suspendisse ac rhoncus massa, eget fermentum augue.<br/> Proin eleifend laoreet velit, sit amet finibus sem volutpat pharetra.<br/>Phasellus feugiat risus in tortor pulvinar aliquam.
</p>

<h2 id="2">Etiam tincidunt nulla vel justo suscipit</h2>
<p>eget interdum nisi suscipit.<br/>Phasellus in tempor mi.<br/>Phasellus venenatis justo mollis suscipit iaculis.<br/>Donec interdum congue lorem.<br/>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi eget massa id neque vehicula  accumsan eu non sem.<br/>Cras pretium lobortis quam, ullamcorper tempus eros viverra non.<br/>Morbi id scelerisque est.<br/>Praesent dictum turpis quam, nec maximus quam cursus ac.<br/>Nam porta quam sit amet velit imperdiet elementum.<br/>Curabitur at orci condimentum, porta enim quis, fermentum orci.<br/>Mauris arcu mauris, tempor at blandit nec, dictum sed augue.<br/>Sed convallis orci vitae lectus commodo posuere.<br/>Aliquam erat volutpat.<br/>Integer sed gravida felis.
</p>

<h2 id="3">Praesent eu sem ex</h2>
<p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst.<br/>Duis interdum turpis sit amet libero consequat, a efficitur turpis vulputate.<br/>Sed non diam malesuada, dignissim leo ut, vulputate nulla.<br/>Quisque tincidunt arcu sed dapibus fermentum.<br/>Vestibulum vitae ultrices velit, ac posuere quam.<br/>Praesent ac ex vitae nisl rhoncus faucibus in at justo.<br/>Pellentesque malesuada imperdiet finibus.<br/>Nunc at aliquam enim, dictum ultricies lectus.<br/>Nam posuere nulla elementum augue fermentum tincidunt.<br/>Sed a tortor non turpis tristique viverra.<br/>Nulla sagittis, sapien vel mollis porttitor, diam felis tempus mi, sit amet scelerisque libero quam sed justo.
</p>

<h2 id="4">
Nam non odio viverra mauris
</h2>
<p>
  aliquam consectetur vel sit amet nisl.<br/>Nam scelerisque turpis ut mattis consectetur.<br/>Donec ut sem iaculis, hendrerit sem at, scelerisque lacus.<br/>Cras sit amet quam bibendum, rutrum nibh vitae, eleifend neque.<br/>Curabitur tincidunt fermentum nibh nec viverra.<br/>Proin tincidunt, tortor vitae sollicitudin commodo, tellus felis commodo felis, nec dictum tellus lorem in nibh.<br/>Cras congue justo at ultrices bibendum.
</p>

<h2 id="5">
Praesent facilisis dapibus ante,
</h2>
<p>
  at consectetur risus dictum et.<br/>Vestibulum ut quam turpis.<br/>Maecenas eu eleifend purus.<br/>Morbi risus mi, feugiat eget auctor eu, convallis in sapien.<br/>Sed egestas vitae lacus sit amet aliquam.<br/>Nullam ullamcorper vulputate ligula sed pulvinar.<br/>Curabitur condimentum mi quis nulla commodo, vitae laoreet magna vulputate.<br/>Ut ultricies ex sit amet eros mattis, vitae faucibus elit blandit.
</p>

<h2 id="6">Mauris ac augue imperdiet</h2>
<p>
  volutpat quam non, cursus leo.<br/>Sed imperdiet semper interdum.<br/>Vivamus blandit est sem, eget facilisis turpis accumsan at.<br/>Duis blandit nisi in mattis pellentesque.<br/>Mauris vitae turpis ullamcorper, tempor nunc et, commodo tellus.<br/>Quisque quis scelerisque ex, quis tincidunt sapien.<br/>Curabitur erat urna, fringilla eget velit in, efficitur venenatis nisi.<br/>Nullam facilisis elit velit, ut maximus libero imperdiet quis.
</p>
```